# What does ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG do?

Tags: java, netty

```
.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
```

is shown in the Netty 4 upgrade doc. Can you explain what it does?

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's a passed through socket option determining the number of connections queued.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

> The maximum queue length for incoming connection indications (a request to connect) is set to the backlog parameter. If a connection indication arrives when the queue is full, the connection is refused.

- More on netty channels: http://seeallhearall.blogspot.de/2012/06/netty-tutorial-part-15-on-channel.html

Comment: Note that the final statement in the Javadoc is incorrect. Whether the connection is refused is platform-dependent, and not under Java's control.

Comment: @EJP, thanks for the clarification. Is there any source for this platform-dependency? I only found something about the *default*: *"The default backlog tends to
OS specific. We try to use a default backlog of 50 (this is not
part of the specification and thus is implementation specific)."*  (http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4304037)

Comment: I discovered it by experiment on Windows, Solaris, Linux, and a few more platforms which I've forgotten. It's also mentioned in a paper cited in my book *Fundamental Networking in Java,* but I don't have a copy to hand.

Comment: So what does it mean then? Regardless of what have been set via this option the behavior is non-deterministic? Or does it only work for epoll event groups?